# "\\" being turned into "\" in a VBNET.FileSystem.Print

Tags: c#

I'm maintaining a program written in C#, but it uses VBNET.Filesystem  I-O for reading and writing files.  I've added a feature to write out a pathname but the text of the pathname is being altered . . .

```
VBNET.FileSystem.FileOpen(ff, path, VBNET.OpenMode.Output,
                          VBNET.OpenAccess.Default,
                          VBNET.OpenShare.Default, -1); 
sTemp = "CONFIGFILE_PATH ";
sTemp = sTemp + _ConfigFilePath;
VBNET.FileSystem.Print(ff, sTemp);
VBNET.FileSystem.PrintLine(ff);
```

sTemp is a String class object.   At write-time it contains

> CONFIGFILE_PATH C:\\Config\\DemoArticles\\00BigTriangle.txt

... but what gets written in the file is

> CONFIGFILE_PATH C:\Config\DemoArticles\00BiggerTriangle.TXT

(**BTW**, I had a similar problem in the StackOverflow editor, so just in case there are browser-dependent rendering problems with this post, the first line contains double backslashes and the second line contains single backslashes)

How do I prevent this?  If the answer is that I need to turn double-backslashes into triple backslashes before writing it, is there an easy way to do that with the C# String class?

Comment: so it really has double slash in it?

Comment: Are you seeing the double slashes when viewing in the debugger?  Because the debugger show escape sequences and thus single slashes will display as double (just like how you would write it in a string literal in code).

Comment: This is entirely correct.  You are just confused about the way the debugger works, it displays the string as a C# literal.  So the backslash is escaped with another backslash.  Use the text visualizer to see what it really looks like, click the spy-glass icon.

Comment: @Hans Passant   The spyglass version only shows single slashes.   That's confusing, but at least it solves the problem.  (**thanks!**) Does Microsoft's debugger report back altered values for other things?

Comment: It simply shows values the way you would write them in a program.  That was meant to make it less confusing :)  And the text visualizer was meant to show what it looks like without that help.

Answer (score 1):

If you preface your string with an @, all control characters will be ignored.

```
"C:\\Config\\DemoArticles\\00BigTriangle.txt"
```

will become

> C:\Config\DemoArticles\00BiggerTriangle.txt

While

```
@"C:\\Config\\DemoArticles\\00BigTriangle.txt"
```

Will stay as you entered it:

> C:\\Config\\DemoArticles\\00BigTriangle.txt

*And you should really kick VB.NET from your C# project. That's horrible.*